# Three.js cylinder rotation in 3d plane

Tags: javascript, three.js

Ive been having the linewidth problem (something to do with ANGLE on window). I have resorted to using cylinders between 2 points (in 3D space). I have already solved the issue on getting the length of the cylinder based on the 2 points-3D distance formula.

I have been having trouble however getting the angle. I want the cylinder to rotate so that the angle found will make it so that the cylinder connects the two points.

Essensially I am trying to find a way to find the angle between (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2). And having it modify a cylinder (cylinder.rotation.x, cylinder.rotation.y, and cylinder.rotation.z).

Comment: This might be a better question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a transformation matrix to do that. Here's some example code:

```
function createCylinderFromEnds( material, radiusTop, radiusBottom, top, bottom, segmentsWidth, openEnded)
{
    // defaults
    segmentsWidth = (segmentsWidth === undefined) ? 32 : segmentsWidth;
    openEnded = (openEnded === undefined) ? false : openEnded;

    // Dummy settings, replace with proper code:
    var length = 100;
    var cylAxis = new THREE.Vector3(100,100,-100);
    var center = new THREE.Vector3(-100,100,100);
    ////////////////////

    var cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( radiusTop, radiusBottom, length, segmentsWidth, 1, openEnded );
    var cyl = new THREE.Mesh( cylGeom, material );

    // pass in the cylinder itself, its desired axis, and the place to move the center.
    makeLengthAngleAxisTransform( cyl, cylAxis, center );

    return cyl;
}

// Transform cylinder to align with given axis and then move to center
function makeLengthAngleAxisTransform( cyl, cylAxis, center )
{
    cyl.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

    // From left to right using frames: translate, then rotate; TR.
    // So translate is first.
    cyl.matrix.makeTranslation( center.x, center.y, center.z );

    // take cross product of cylAxis and up vector to get axis of rotation
    var yAxis = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    // Needed later for dot product, just do it now;
    // a little lazy, should really copy it to a local Vector3.
    cylAxis.normalize();
    var rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3();
    rotationAxis.crossVectors( cylAxis, yAxis );
    if ( rotationAxis.length() < 0.000001 )
    {
        // Special case: if rotationAxis is just about zero, set to X axis,
        // so that the angle can be given as 0 or PI. This works ONLY
        // because we know one of the two axes is +Y.
        rotationAxis.set( 1, 0, 0 );
    }
    rotationAxis.normalize();

    // take dot product of cylAxis and up vector to get cosine of angle of rotation
    var theta = -Math.acos( cylAxis.dot( yAxis ) );
    //cyl.matrix.makeRotationAxis( rotationAxis, theta );
    var rotMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotMatrix.makeRotationAxis( rotationAxis, theta );
    cyl.matrix.multiply( rotMatrix );
}
```

I didn't write this. Find the full working sample [here](https://github.com/udacity/cs291/blob/master/unit5/unit5-ps_cylinder_exercise.js).
It's part of Chapter 5: Matrices from this awesome free [Interactive 3D Graphics course](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs291) taught using three.js.

[image: Interactive 3D Graphics course]

I warmly recommend it. If you didn't have a chance to play with transformations you might want to start with Chapter 4.

As a side note. You can also cheat a bit and use Matrix4's `lookAt()` to solve the rotation, offset the translation so the pivot is at the tip of the cylinder, then apply the matrix to the cylinder.